# Save short array to MySQL db with JDBC?

Tags: java, mysql, arrays, jdbc, short

Title pretty much says everything.

This is what I tried;

```
Short[] messageObj = new Short[] { 1, 2, 3 };
PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO table (audioData) VALUES (?)");
stmt.setArray(1, stmt.getConnection().createArrayOf("short", messageObj));
stmt.executeUpdate();
```

`audioData` column's type is `varbinary(8200)`. I am not sure what to use.

Comment: Can arrays vary in size? Do they have a maximum size?

Comment: Yes. It actually is 8200.

Comment: That is 8200 bytes, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The JConnector JDBC drivers map `VARBINARY` to the Java `byte[]` type.  So you need to convert your `Short[]` into a `byte[]`  before you can save them.

Reference:

- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/en/connector-j-reference-type-conversions.html

Comment: @fge - except that he (supposedly) is starting with a `Short[]` not a `short[]`.

Comment: Is there actually a `toByteAray` method for `ShortBuffer`? Or is it just an example?

Comment: @m_poorUser - did you read the javadoc?  I'm **sure** that it will answer that question.

Comment: I couldn't see it in javadoc, this is why I asked. I was referring fge's deleted comment.